# ¿Por qué una ventana con animación en wpf abre pero la animación queda congelada?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Estoy tratando de abrir una ventana que tiene animación desde otra ventana pero dicha animación nunca sucede, muestra la ventana pero queda estático.
Tratando de solucionar me topé con `Dispatcher.Run()`, el código quedó así:

```
Llamada_ticket lt = new Llamada_ticket();
lt.TicketEntrante(newcall[0], newcall[1]);
lt.Show();
Dispatcher.Run();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
lt.Close();
```

Y la ventana con la animación se abre y funciona bien, pero nunca vuelve a cerrarla, cosa que necesito que haga automáticamente luego de X segundos.
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo, primero dices que abre pero la animación "nunca sucede" luego que se abre con la animación  y funciona bien pero nunca se cierra... Podrías colocar el constructor completo de tu ventana para saber exactamente como haces el proceso?

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien, al principio la animación no se cargaba pero la ventana sí se cerraba después de X segundos, luego de buscar otra solución fue que le coloqué el `Dispatcher.Run()`, ahí sí cargaba la animación pero la ventana nunca se volvía a cerrar.

Comment: Olvide mencionarte @Leodev

Comment: Ok, ok, el problema es que no sabes lo que hace Dispatcher.Run, la razón de que tu ventana no se cierre es que el proceso se queda colgado en esa instrucción. Mira hay varias soluciones, te las voy a colocar como respuesta a ver si alguna te ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de salir de este problema, depende de varios factores, pero yo intentaría una de estas:

1: Cerrar al ventana a través del hilo principal de gestión de GUI

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lt.Close();
    }));
```

2: Cerrar la ventana llamando al componente Dispatcher, que como ya habrás adivinado tiene algo que ver con el manejo de hilos.

```
lt.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    lt.Close();
}));
```

3: Lo que yo haría, en vez de poner un `Thread.Sleep` para que el sistema espere (y de paso se congele, razón por la que no debes usarlo) es, en el constructor de la ventana inicializar un temporizador que pasados 3 segundos cierre la propia ventana desde dentro, algo más o menos así.

```
private DispatcherTimer CloseTimer;

public Llamada_ticket (object param1, object param2)
{
    DispatcherTimer CloseTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    CloseTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    CloseTimer.Tick += CloseTimer_Tick;
    CloseTimer.Start();
}

void CloseTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CloseTimer.IsEnabled = false;
    this.Close();
}
```

Aps! Me faltó la opción más importante:
Simplemente detener el Dispatcher! el Dispatcher es un bucle de hilos, no se detiene hasta que tu lo hagas:

```
Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown
```

Ahora si, saludos!

Comment: he probado todas y ninguna me funcionó, sospecho que es problema de hilos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y disculpa la tardanza en responder!